# Array adapter with custom subclass objects

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

The solution is in the bottom:

I made some classes that i want to use in a listview.
They look like this:

```
public class Equipment{
       ....code....
}
```

and

```
public class Weapon extends Equipment{
        ...More code...
}
```

and

```
public class Armor extends Equipment{
        ...More code...
}
```

As you can see weapon and armor extends equipment. Now i want to use theese classes in the same ArrayAdapter. In my imagination it would be simple as this:

```
public class ShopItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Equipment>{
private List<Equipment> itemList;
    public ShopItemAdapter(Context context, List<Equipment> itemList) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
    }
     .... CODE ....
}
```

But for some reason I may not create an ArrayAdapter Equipment with List Weapon or List Armor.

```
ShopItemAdapter adapter = new ShopItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), weaponList);
```

This codes gives me the error that ShopItemAdapter(Context, List) is undefined

Am I using subclasses in the wrong way or what?

My goal is to show a list of armors when clicking on a button and viseversa.

Hope my problem is clear. Thanks!

SOLUTION **
So i just needed to change the constructor to receive  then cast to List in the super constructor.

```
public class ShopItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Equipment>{
private List<Equipment> itemList;
    public ShopItemAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Equipment> itemList) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, (List<Equipment>)itemList);
    this.itemList = (List<Equipment>)itemList;
    this.context = context;
    }
     .... CODE ....
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messags @Furedal?

Comment: Your idea is correct but the actual implementation maybe not. What is the exact problem?

Comment: When creating an adapter i get the error "The constructor ShopItemAdapter(Context, List<Weapon>) is undefined. Do need to create a constructor for every List types? Seems weird as Weapon extends Equipment. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When creating an adapter i get the error "The constructor ShopItemAdapter(Context, List) is undefined. Do need to create a constructor for every List types? Seems weird as Weapon extends Equipment. :(

No, but you need to specify that any subclass of `Equipment` will also do:

```
public ShopItemAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Equipment> itemList) {
```

`?` is a wildcard in Java generics and `? extends A` makes it bound to type `A` or its subclasses.

Comment: I tried <? extends Equipment> but
     public class ShopItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<? extends Equipment>

gives me the error "A supertype may not specify any wildcard"

Comment: I tried public ShopItemAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Equipment> itemList) { worked. I just forgot to cast it to equipment when calling the super constructor. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is fine, but you will also have to override getView() and populate your layout there. The default is for ArrayAdapter to populate a single TextView.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you only use fields available in `Equipment`, that should be ok.